# Using a Fragment Layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmenttransaction, fragmentmanager

My Android app has a requirement where a certain flow has 7 different screens. Now each of these screens has a common top and bottom. So i have chosen to create a `FragmentActivity` and 7 different `Fragments`. How do I insert the fragments into the `FragmentActivity` at runtime? I have read this tutorial [here](http://neilgoodman.net/2012/01/29/working-with-fragments-on-android-part-1/), and according to this tutorial my main `FragmentActivity` should have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And it should use the following code to replace the fragment:

```
 FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
 Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_content); 

 if (fragment == null) {
     FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
     ft.add(R.id.fragment_content, new BasicFragment());
     ft.commit();
 }
```

What I don't understand is the following line:

```
 ft.add(R.id.fragment_content, new BasicFragment());
```

`R.id.fragment_content` is a `FrameLayout`, will this insert the fragment into the `FrameLayout` or what?

Comment: It should be using a `tag` to identify the `Fragment`. You use `id` if your `Fragment`s are in xml, which is not the case here, you are adding them programmatically (the better approach).

Answer (score 0):

> R.id.fragment_content is a FrameLayout ? will this insert the fragment into the framelayout or what ?

From what I remember Fragment layout is being placed on top of it. Underneath it, it has another layout that is a "sticker gluing" it to the container layout. So it's a cake in a way. 
To get a hold of that "sticker", I think, you may call `.getParent()` on root view of a Fragment.

Oh, and tag fragments to easily find them through `FragmentManager`(though tag lookup is a tad expensive).

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this like you have a pool (your `FrameLayout` in this case) that you can throw toy ships into (your `Fragments`). So basically you need an environment to contain you `Fragments` and it could be any layout you choose.

So what you are doing here:

```
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_content);
```

is wrong because `R.id.fragment_content` is not a `Fragment` but a `FrameLayout`.

but it could be your `Fragment` container, So you need to create a class that `extends Fragment` with it's own layout and do the operation you did here:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.fragment_content, new BasicFragment(), tag);  //add a tag to a fragment during the transaction so you could easily retrieve it later.
ft.commit();
```

and of course you could understand a lot more about fragments by reading this page:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html